# flutter / firestore get searched field and check other field through documentId

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, field, snapshot

i am trying to get the searched value(userid) which is in the field of a document in firestore i want to check the other fields(status) of the document i tried this method but failed

```
handlesubmit(BuildContext context)async{

   final QuerySnapshot searcheduserid=
                   await Firestore.instance.collection('users')
                .where('userid',isEqualTo: userid).limit(1).getDocuments();

   final userdocid=searcheduserid.documents.map((doc)=>doc.documentID);

   final DocumentSnapshot getuserdoc= await Firestore.instance.collection('users')
                          .document(userdocid).get();

   final userstatus = getuserdoc.data['status'];//  I GET AN ERROR HERE ERROR SAYS

   // METHOD [](status) was called on null

 if(userstatus==null){
 return showdialog( context,'the entered user id status does not exist');
}
```

}

thank you <3

Comment: Hi! It's possible that `getuserdoc` doesn't have any data in it. You should check it before try to access it values.

Comment: how do i get that data or is there a problem here  //.document(userdocid)

Comment: What do you get if you `print(userdocid)` after you set it?

Comment: i get the exact document id of the field

Comment: And what do you get inside getuserdoc.data when you print it? Is it possible that your Firestore collection 'users' doesn't have that documentId?